# How do I remove ubuntu from a windows 7 machine without the recovery disk?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall

I have a computer that originally came with windows 7.  I recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 (natty) on it.  Now, I want to remove it from the computer while keeping windows.  Unfortunately, I don't have the windows recovery disk anymore... Is there a way I can delete ubuntu without deleting the booting program (the purple screen where you can select the operating system)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to keep Ubuntu bootloader (GRUB) if you're removing Ubuntu? I'm not sure it's possible because I believe GRUB stores some of its files on the partition you're going to remove.

I believe you need to [re-install Windows boot loader](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392), then you just boot into Windows and delete Ubuntu partition using standard Windows tools. You may be able to resize the windows partition to take up the free space or create a new NTFS partition there.

(as such, the question turns out to be totally unrelated to Ubuntu... you can do everything in Windows)

Comment: I'm not sure how to re-install the windows boot loader, since I don't have the recovery disk... is there another way? (a way that is free?)

Comment: Do you have Windows Recovery partition on your hard drive? After selecting Windows from GRUB's menu and pressing Enter - does pressing and holding F8 launches the Win Recovery Environment?

Comment: Also, have you tried creating a recovery disk following the recipe @Misery linked to?

Answer (score 2):

google for easy bcd and install it while in windows. With this program you can create the MBR needed for the windows onls system. After that you can delete ubuntu partition and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to create recovery disc:
howtogeek.com/howto/5409/create-a-system-repair-disc-in-windows-7/
if that seems more convenient to You.

If needed You can use Windows bootloader. In menu start write msconfig and press enter. Than in boot options You have to find option: other systems display time or something similar. Set value to 30 sec.
regards

Answer (score 0):

**How To Delete Ubuntu From An Ubuntu + Windows 7 Dual Boot:**

This will allow you to remove Ubuntu, while maintaining access to Windows 7. You will still be using Grub.

1. Download "Parted Magic" and burn it to a dvd. (Or you can use an ubuntu live cd)
   [http://sourceforge.net/projects/partedmagic/files/partedmagic/Parted%20Magic%205.7/pmagic-5.7.iso]
2. Boot "Parted Magic" and select "Run From Ram"
3. Open Gparted, and delete your ubuntu parition(s), and swap partition.
4. Reboot into windows, and install "EasyBCD"
   [http://cdn.neosmart.net/software/EasyBCD/community/EasyBCD%202.2.exe]
5. Using EasyBCD remove the Ubuntu entries from your bootloader.
6. Uninstall EasyBCD

PLEASE NOTE: If your windows partition is BEFORE your Ubuntu partitions, you can safely expand the windows partition to use that space up, if you do this from linux you will get a disk check error upon booting windows the first time, don't worry, let disk check examine your disk, which should only take a few minutes.

Sincerely, tapthoseshoesandwish

Sources:
http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=532.0